# Convert à into /351 type of codes

Tags: javascript

I have à in Javascript Alert. Its crashing. I have used \351 for é and it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what code to use for à ?

Comment: A Javascript alert shouldn't "crash" when using accented characters. You're barking up the wrong tree for a solution here.

Comment: @deceze It does crashes in some cases. For most cases it works fine, But its does crash, So these codes are the perfect solution for it

Comment: What does "crash" mean? Computer shuts down and reboots? No, probably not. Describe your actual error and we can help you solve it. Using  escape codes is not fixing the core problem you have, which will come back to bite you later again and again until you understand and fix it.

Comment: Just use UTF-8 / Unicode (everywhere) and you are safe with whatever char is entered

Answer (score 1):

This number is called an ASCII code. A complete list can be found here:

http://www.ascii-code.com/

There you see the code for à is \340

This is the result for

```
alert("\340");
```

[image]

Comment: That won't work, try `alert(\340)` - you'll get `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Try alert("\340"); with quotes, in Chrome on OSX it works.